# SSH ignores key in agent and keeps asking for key decryption password

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, ssh-agent

In my `ssh_config`, I have configured SSH to use a specific key when connecting to a host. I want SSH to try *only* this key, not any other key it may find (in ssh agent or some other location), so I specified `IdentitiesOnly`, too.

```
Host *.foobar.com
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/keys/id_ed25519
   IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Now, the key is password-protected for better security. To avoid typing the password every time, I've added it to `ssh-agent` (along with some other key):

```
$ ssh-add -l
256 SHA256:1seMMJNjoexbRqNlVDe9kxkWm8s7fKAEuo+dP+hYut0 (ED25519)
2048 SHA256:p5SXMJNjoexbRqNl8roRamdzz+HFVlRKxtQoEW3vLu0 (RSA)
```

However, when I try to connect, SSH keeps asking me for password to decrypt the key. Why? When I changed configuration to enforce using the other key from the agent, it worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out that, even though only private keys are necessary for connecting to hosts, using `ssh-agent` requires public keys to work correctly. I guess SSH identifies the keys available in the agent by their public part - without them it thinks that the key is not available.

The reason that the other key worked was because I had a corresponding public key next to the private key - it looked like this:

```
~/.ssh/keys
├── id_ed25519
├── id_rsa
└── id_rsa.pub
```

After adding public key `id_ed25519.pub` (corresponding to the private key `id_ed25519`), everything started working as expected.